# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference in BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wpf

Hi I have developed scanner application using XAML WPF bt refering below link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-wpf-browser-application-to-scan-a-document-from-scanneradf-and-flatbed-using-wia After scanning and saving file in specified location I am returning back filename to javascript functionas below.

```
    var uploadData = [];
    var ContentData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode((Objcontent)));
    window.ResponseAlert = function (responseData)
```

I am getting below error. 
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Please find the below error screen shot.
[image: Scanner Error]

I am not able to find the what is the cause for error but i am getting error in the below line.

```
var hostScript = BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript;
   hostScript.document.ResponseData(filename);
```

May i get some help here to find what is giving me error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is your view binding to an object that has no meaning in your view model?

Comment: Thanks. I am accessing scanner app using iframe. I am not clear about what you have asked.

Comment: In your xaml for whatever view you are hitting this issue for is there a binding which is incorrect

Comment: i am getting error in   hostScript.document.ResponseData(filename); May i know what should i change? Thanks

Comment: <iframe src="https://scanner.kyctest.c3card.com/C3CKYC Scanner.xbap?Param=@ViewBag.FileName" width="1000" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe> Using this iframe i am accessing the scanner.